# HTML 5 CSS 3 @viewport mediaquery

Tags: html, css, viewport

So i was browsing the web to see if there was any solution to lock orientation. I have found this:

> http://www.w3.org/TR/css-device-adapt/

It states that with @viewport you should be able to lock orientation but i can't find any information on support or whatever. I just tried

```
 @viewport{
orientation: portrait;
}
```

But it does nothing, any toughts about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add vendor prefix.

Example:

**IE10**

```
@-ms-viewport {
  width: 1024px;
  height: 768px;
}
```

Read more http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh708740(v=vs.85).aspx

**Opera**

```
@-o-viewport {
  width: 1024px;
  height: 768px;
}
```

Read more http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/an-introduction-to-meta-viewport-and-viewport/

http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/atrules/@viewport

Comment: thx for the answer, it seems that orientation locking still isn't possible tough :(

Comment: Voted Christopher back up because there was no descent documentation half a year ago

Answer (score 0):

```
@viewport all and (max-width: 480px) {
 orientation:portrait;
}
```

Can't test, but I believe this behaves the same as the `@media` CSS.

Comment: will try this myself and post back in a minute :)

Comment: You'll have to change the width to your specs, and either use min/max if you'd like. But I'm interested as well. Good luck!

Comment: tried it with ipad2 and no success :( used
@viewport all and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
 orientation:portrait;
}

Comment: D: Sorry dude. I tried googling a result but didn't come up with any good results.

Comment: Do you have <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> tag in the head?